# HOW TO CONVERT STRING INTO INTEGER

Tags: javascript, string, parsing, numbers, integer

hi i am having a big issue in my almost complete program that i am unable to convert my string into integer and adding it up further. i know it is easy and can be done with `parsetInt()` and `number()` but it has become a headache for me kndliy lookout my code and help me please so that i can get my desired result not `NaN`

code is here:

```
var operator = document.getElementById(ButtonIds).value;
    var Quantity = document.getElementById(QuantityIds).value;

    GetQuantity = Number(Quantity);
    testing = parseInt(GetQuantity);

    if(operator == '+') {
        testing = testing + 1;
    }
    else {
        testing = testing - 1;
    }
    alert(testing);

    document.getElementById(QuantityIds).innerHTML=testing;
```

thanks...

Comment: Also provide the HTML and where e,g, the `QuantityIds` gets assigned.

Comment: Calling `Number()` and then `parseInt()` doesn't make sense; just call `parseInt()`.Also declare your variables with `var` or `let`!

Comment: i m getting this QuantityIds  by making it my self

Comment: sir i have declare the variable globally and using here

Comment: by calling one function it is still not working

Comment: <p  class="ProductQuantity" id="800000'+[i]+'">'+CheckoutNames[1][i]+'</p>             this is how i am making ids @LGSon

Comment: There's no `<input>` there, what are you getting the value of?

Comment: the input is in table and it is still being generated with javascript

Comment: it has id "8000000" and QuantityIds  = 8000000

Comment: <<p  class="ProductQuantity" id="800000'+[i]+'">'+CheckoutNames[1][i]+'</p>>

Comment: You might want to read [ask] and especially [mcve]

Comment: thankss alot @LGSon

Answer (score -1):

```js
function myFunction(){
var operator = document.getElementById("operator").value;
    var Quantity = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
if(operator.trim().length&&Quantity.trim().length){

    var GetQuantity = Number(Quantity);
    var testing = parseInt(GetQuantity);

    if(operator == '+') {
        testing = testing + 1;
    }
    else {
        testing = testing - 1;
    }
    alert(testing);

    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=testing; 
    } else {
     document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="<b style='color:"+ 
     "red;'>Please enter an operator and a quantity!</b>";
   }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<label>
Operator: 
<input type="text" id="operator"/>
</label>
<br/>
<label>
Quantity: 
<input type="text" id="quantity"/>
</label>
<br/>
<button onClick="myFunction()">
Do The Math
</button>
<br/>
Result:
<br/>
<span id="result"></span>
</body>
</html>
```